# jQuery prepend not for subelements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get work menu with dropdown options.

**My task:**

I need to add span element to level 1 menu items, with script below I unfortunately add the span element also to the dropdown options

**Menu CODE structure:**

```
<li class="menu-item-1"><a href="#">Item1</a>
<li class="menu-item-2"><a href="#">Item2</a>    
<li class="menu-item-3">
  <a href="#">Item3</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu dropdown">
    <li class="menu-item-4"><a href="#">Subitem1</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item-4"><a href="#">Subitem1</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

**my not proper jQuery solution**

```
$('.menu-item-552 a:not(.dropdown)').prepend('<span class="span-1"></span>');
$('.menu-item-553 a:not(.dropdown)').prepend('<span class="span-2"></span>');
$('.menu-item-561 a:not(.dropdown)').prepend('<span class="span-3"></span>');
$('.menu-item-559 a:not(.dropdown)').prepend('<span class="span-4"></span>');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Target only the child element of the element with said class - use child selector instead of descendant selector

```
$('.menu-item-552 > a').prepend('<span class="span-1"></span>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `not` to filter `a` elements for `.dropdown` despite the fact its actually a class applied to `ul`:

`$('ul:not(.dropdown) .menu-item-552 a').prepend('<span class="span-1"></span>');`